# How to add button in grid like manner in windows phone

Tags: c#, wpf, button, windows-phone-8, grid

I am new to windows phone,

I want to display 8 buttons in grid like manner.

for eg:

```
button 1           button 2

button 3           button 4

button 5           button 6

button 7           button 8
```

(Something like this..)

[image]:
How to achieve this ?

**Thanx in advance**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a grid control, with 2 cols and 4 rows. You can then add buttons and assign them to grid row / cols with attached properties like this. You can adjust column widths etc by changing the `ColumnDefinitions` appropriately:

```
<Grid Width="100%">
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Button Name="btn1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Click="OnClick1">
        Button 1
      </Button>
      <Button Name="btn2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Click="OnClick2">
        Button 2
      </Button>
      <!-- More buttons in here as required... -->
</Grid>
```

*EDIT:* Added support for clicks. In  your .cs...

```
    void OnClick1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Clicked button 1
    }

    void OnClick2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Clicked button 2
    }
```

Comment: Pretty sure he is going to need 4 rows.

Comment: Indeed, was just finishing off

Comment: excellent dude! woks like charm.. but how to identify which button is clicked ?

Comment: @Krunal see my edit. You could also add a `Tag` to your buttons and use the same handler if you wish, reading the value of the sender's `Tag` property in the handler

Comment: Dude only final doubt ;) What if number of rows is not fixed ?

Comment: You can add more `RowDefinitions` dynamically with C#, or just add more shapes stacked vertically inside each cell. Please mark as answer if this has helped.

Answer (score 0):

Adding it inside a stackpanel is also very easy

A structure, Something like this

```
<Stackpanel Orientation="Vertical">
<stackpanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAllignment="Center">
<!--Button1-->
<Button/>
<!--Button2-->
<Button/>
<Stackpanel>
<stackpanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAllignment="Center">
<!--Button3-->
<Button/>
<!--Button4-->
<Button/>
<Stackpanel>
<stackpanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAllignment="Center">
<!--Button5-->
<Button/>
<!--Button6-->
<Button/>
<Stackpanel>
<stackpanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAllignment="Center">
<!--Button7-->
<Button/>
<!--Button8-->
<Button/>
<Stackpanel>
</Stackpanel>
```

Comment: Yes, this would work but you lose the advantages that `Grid` brings for this kind of layout, like aligning the controls to columns for example.

Comment: yes, grid is more flexible.